# Flutter | Update checkbox on all screens in Navigator stack from top most screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Hi In my Flutter application I have to add checkboxes on few screens.
For example If I have 6 Screens as Screen1, Screen2, Screen3,Screen4, Screen5 and Screen6 and I can navigate from screen1 to Screen2, Screen2 to Screen3 and so on.

My screen Stack Example

Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> Screen4 -> Screen5 -> Screen6

Here Screen1 is my root and Screen6 is top most screen.

If I have a checkboxes on Screen1, Screen2, Screen4 and Screen6 as

Screen1(checkbox) -> Screen2(checkbox) -> Screen3 -> Screen4(checkbox) -> Screen5 -> Screen6(checkbox)

Now Problem is that If I check Checkbox of screen6 than checkboxes on all other screen must be selected(checked) automatically (Without passing result back)

I am using flutter_block package.

Please help.

**Edited**

Same thing required if top Screen(in navigator stack) is Screen4 or Screen2

Answer (score 1):

Using BLOC you can store checkboxes in a state and use bloc `events` to trigger configuration changes to that state (check/uncheck the options).

Every time you call/add an event, in the BLOC, you should take the previous state, modify (check/uncheck an option) and emit a new state. When a new state is emitted all `BlocBuilders` are re-rendered so all your screens are up-to-date (this is how Flutter BLOC actually works).

Now the most important think is to provide the created BLOC globally or make THE SAME BLOC INSTANCE available to all your screens (using `BlocProvider.value` - also check the attach tutorial on this topic). In this way every time you want to RENDER the checkboxes using `BlocBuilder` you will get the same checkboxes/state on all screens.

I have created a full EXAMPLE for you to illustrate all of the above. Just copy into main.dart and Run. Take some time to read the comments and apologies for the mistakes if any (it took a little to write it).

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

///
/// I put the checkboxes globally because I do not know how you have access to
/// them but you are free to put whenever you want as soon as they are passed
/// to the BLOC. You can even add them inside the BLOC.
///
final List<Checky> gCheckboxes = [
  Checky("Checkbox 1"),
  Checky("Checkbox 2"),
  Checky("Checkbox 3"),
  Checky("Checkbox 4"),
  Checky("Checkbox 5"),
  Checky("Checkbox 6"),
  Checky("Checkbox 7"),
];

void main() {
  runApp(CheckyApp());
}

///
/// This widget is the root of your application.
///
class CheckyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // For demo sake I will expose the BLOC globally
    return BlocProvider<CheckyCubit>(
        create: (context) => CheckyCubit(gCheckboxes),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Checky App',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          initialRoute: "/screen_1",
          routes: {
            '/screen_1': (context) => GenericScreen(1),
            '/screen_2': (context) => GenericScreen(2),
            '/screen_3': (context) => GenericScreen(3),
            '/screen_4': (context) => GenericScreen(4),
            '/screen_5': (context) => GenericScreen(5),
            '/screen_6': (context) => SummaryScreen(),
          },
        ));
  }
}

///
/// A generic screen to demonstrate that data can be accessed among multiple
/// screens
///
class GenericScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ///
  /// This is used to create the generic screen and navigation buttons
  ///
  final int id;

  const GenericScreen(this.id, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Checky :: Screen ${this.id}"),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<CheckyCubit, CheckyState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.checkboxes.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  // Render the checkbox based on state data from BLOC.
                  // Here I just emulated the checkbox for the sake of example
                  GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    BlocProvider.of<CheckyCubit>(context).toggle(index),
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  color: state.checkboxes[index].isChecked
                      ? Colors.amberAccent
                      : Colors.white,
                  child: Text(state.checkboxes[index].label),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      // THIS IS NOT IMPORTART FOR YOUR PURPOSE
      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop())
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "previous_$id",
              child: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      if (this.id <= 5)
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "next_$id",
              child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
              onPressed: () =>
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/screen_${id + 1}"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ]);
  }
}

///
/// Last screen where we just display the values by accessing the CheckyBloc.
///
class SummaryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SummaryScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Checky :: Summary"),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<CheckyCubit, CheckyState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.checkboxes.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  // Render only checked options
                  state.checkboxes[index].isChecked
                      ? Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          color: state.checkboxes[index].isChecked
                              ? Colors.greenAccent
                              : Colors.white,
                          child: Text(state.checkboxes[index].label),
                        )
                      : SizedBox.shrink(),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            heroTag: "Reset",
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              // Reset the options
              BlocProvider.of<CheckyCubit>(context).reset();
              // Push to the first screen
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/screen_1");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

// =============================================================================

///
/// Checkbox entity which stores the label and whether is selected or not.
///
class Checky {
  ///
  /// Checkbox displayed label
  ///
  final String label;

  ///
  /// Tells whether the checkbox is selected
  ///
  bool isChecked;

  ///
  /// Checkbox constructor. Default the checkbox is unchecked.
  ///
  Checky(this.label, {this.isChecked = false});

  ///
  /// Check the checkbox ;)
  ///
  void check() {
    this.isChecked = true;
  }

  ///
  /// Uncheck the checkbox ;)
  ///
  void uncheck() {
    this.isChecked = false;
  }

  ///
  /// Uncheck the checkbox ;)
  ///
  void toggle() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
  }
}

///
/// Checkboxes state that is sent from BLOC and only contains a list of
/// checkboxes (current checkboxes configuration).
///
class CheckyState {
  ///
  /// The checkboxes list
  ///
  final List<Checky> checkboxes;

  CheckyState(this.checkboxes);
}

///
/// Checkboxes logic. Takes the current state and modifies the checkboxes and
/// then emit the new configuration on the "output" stream.
///
class CheckyCubit extends Cubit<CheckyState> {
  ///
  /// Cubit constructor which emits the first/default checkboxes and their
  /// configuration (ehich one are checked or not).
  ///
  CheckyCubit(List<Checky> checkboxes) : super(CheckyState(checkboxes));

  // ==================================
  // EVENTS
  // ==================================

  ///
  /// Toggle a checkbox by index
  ///
  void toggle(int index) async {
    // Retrieve the current checkboxes from the last emited state
    var checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;

    // Just take some precautions but this depends by your implementation
    if (checkboxes != null && checkboxes[index] != null) {
      // Toggle the checkbox by given index
      checkboxes[index].toggle();
    }
    // Emit the new state/configuration
    emit(CheckyState(checkboxes));
  }

  ///
  /// Reset the entire by unchecking all options.
  ///
  void reset() {
    // Retrieve the current checkboxes
    var checkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;

    // Uncheck all of them
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) {
      checkbox.uncheck();
    });

    // Emit the new state/configuration
    emit(CheckyState(checkboxes));
  }
}
```

Also if you want to know more about Flutter BLOC please watch [this series (Flutter BLOC from ZERO to HERO)](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLptHs0ZDJKt_T-oNj_6Q98v-tBnVf-S_o) - especially Episode #6 which explains some concepts that can help on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for You answer I have implemented Similar Approach.

Answer (score 0):

**For this purpose you can use BLOC which may be difficult for begineers but another hack for this is to create another class on separate dart file. let's say**

```
show the six checked box as Constants.box1 == "selected" ? Showcheckedbox() : showUncheckedBox()  

 // ? means if condition is true : means if condition is false

class Constants {
     string box1 ;
     string box2 ;
     string box3 ;
     string box4 ;
     string box5 ;

}

1. now, when you select the box1 as checked then there you can write it as Constants.box1= "selected";  

 2. and when you pop the screen there you can setState({}) on pop out the screen.
```

Comment: Please check my edited part. I am looking for callback which can update each check box on all screen in case of selection of any checkbox on any screen.